# How to make an animated gif loop twice in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I need to make an animated gif that plays all of its frames twice before stopping. It might seem like a simple thing to do, but for some reason when I set the -loop flag to 2, it plays three times, whereas when I set it to 1, it plays only once. so:

```
#this will play once then stop
convert -size 300x600 -delay 50 frame1.png  -delay 50 frame2.png -loop 1 animation.gif;

#this will play three times then stop
convert -size 300x600 -delay 50 frame1.png  -delay 50 frame2.png -loop 2 animation.gif;
```

How to make it play twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that this is a bug in ImageMagick. As a workaround, I can only suggest you list your frames twice and set `-loop` to 1, like this:

```
convert -size 300x600 -delay 50 frame1.png frame2.png frame1.png frame2.png -loop 1 animation.gif
```

Comment: Thank you. We also came to the conclusion that it's a bug. Another way to correct it is to change the loop setting using gifsicle afterwards, but that requires another library.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=592735
When you set `-loop` to 1，ImageMagick don't write the looping extension.